# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'options' before initialization but 'options' is initalized before use

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I really am clueless at this point and have tried looking up everything I could think of, I am getting this error with my code:

```sh
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'options' before initialization
at file:///D:/node mods/agda.js/src/constants/Constants.js:4:45
```

Constants.js

```js
import { options } from "../ws/WebSocketManager.js";

export const Constants = {
    GATEWAY: `wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=${options.gateway_version}&encoding=json`
}
```

WebSocketManager.js (only showing a snippet)

```js
import WebSocket from 'ws';
import { Constants } from '../constants/Constants.js';
import { OPCodes } from '../constants/OPCodes.js';
import { Heartbeat, Identify } from '../constants/Payloads.js';

export const options = {
    debugMode: true,
    debugMode_payloads: true,
    debugMode_connection: true,
    debugMode_heartbeats: true,
    useOS: 'linux',
    intents: 513,
    gateway_version: '9'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it, though with a sort of different approach.

For those that may need it,

```js
export const Gateway = {
    URL: undefined,
    VERSION: 9
}

Gateway.URL = `wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=${Gateway.VERSION}&encoding=json`;
```